# Authenticating with JWT on Signalr hub ends with 401 with Authorize attribute

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, signalr, blazor-server-side

I am trying to use Signalr with the following JWT options

```
.AddJwtBearer(options => {
       
        options.TokenValidationParameters =new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateAudience=false,
            ValidateIssuer=true,
            ValidateLifetime=true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey=true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience=builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),


        };
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

               
                var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && (path.StartsWithSegments("/ConnectionsHub")))
                {
                    context.Token = accessToken;
                    context.Response.Headers.Authorization = accessToken;
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
})
...
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, NameUserIdProvider>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, CustomEmailProvider>();
```

but when I sending the Authentication token to the  signalr client it throws 401 if I used Authorize attribute on top of the Hub but without the Attribute i see that no Identity user is recognized on GetUserId(returns null and there arent any claims)

```
    public class CustomEmailProvider : IUserIdProvider
    {
        public virtual string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
        {
            
            var res = connection.User?.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Type==ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            return res?.Value;
        }
    }
```

So what could I be possibly doing wrong with the JWT authentication? it is worth noting that I am using a blazor server side project and Identity

Comment: From the configuration of jwt in your demo, I don't find anything error, You need to check if the JWT which you send to hub is correct and make sure the  order of middleware is correct .

Comment: @XinranShen I found a way i need to manually asign the  ClaimsPrincipal on the HttpContext when the Url contain the token